# Determining the equivalence of different subsets, unions and intersections?

Tags: logic

I'm currently working on some discrete mathematics work and I've encountered a question I'm not sure how to answer exactly. Precisely, I'm trying to prove that three separate statements are logically equivalent and my understanding of how to do that doesn't seem to be enough. The statements in question go as follows:

> Prove that the three statements $A \subseteq E$, $A \cap \bar{E} =
>  \varnothing$, and $\bar{A} \cup E = U$, where $U$ is a universal set,
>   are equivalent.

Should I make some form of example set to better understand how these statements are equivalent? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Draw a Venn Diagram. Then the solution will more or less write itself.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
A\subseteq E
&=\left\{x\in U|x\in A\to x\in E\right\}\\
&=\left\{x\in U|x\not\in A\lor x\in E\right\}\equiv\bar{A}\cup E\\
&=\left\{x\in U|\neg\left(x\in A\land x\not\in E\right)\right\}\\
&=\left\{x\in U|\neg\left(x\in A\land x\not\in E\right)\lor x\in\emptyset\right\}\\
&=\left\{x\in U|\left(x\in A\land x\not\in E\right)\to x\in\emptyset\right\}\equiv\left(A\cap\bar{E}=\emptyset\right)\Box
\end{align}